# System.Drawing.Image out of memory on jpeg pictures

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am adding watermark on pictures. After a few pictures, `System.Drawing.Image` gives an error - of out of memory. I have 2 thousand pictures in my folder. I also dispose my object and also `using` in `using`, but it's still running out of memory.

```
Using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path)))
{
  using ( Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height))
  { 
        Graphics pic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 11);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
        pic.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
        pic.DrawString(location, font, brush, 0f, bmp.Height - 20);
        pic.DrawString(date, font, brush, 300, bmp.Height - 20);
        System.Drawing.Image img3 = (System.Drawing.Image) bmp;
        string NewPath = path.Insert(path.IndexOf('.'), "-wm");
        img3.Save(Server.MapPath(NewPath));
        img3.Dispose();
        bmp.Dispose();
        img.Dispose();
        font.Dispose();
        pic.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
  }
}
```

This is the code, and all of my pictures are in jpeg format.

Comment: Can you check, you get this exception on a certain image or not?

Comment: I just thought about **LOH** - and that it could be a problem with that. Perhaps your *LOH is fragmented too much*, so that a new object cannot be allocated. see *[LOH-CompactionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)* What framework version do you use?

Comment: hi think problem is with the pictures some of my pictures pixels are not match with Image class

Comment: Did you try a `GC.Collect(..)` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect(v=vs.110).aspx) ) or anything comparable to that?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz ok thanks for it now i am reading it

Comment: A lot of your code is unessessory at the end. `img3` does not need to exist, just call `bmp.Save`, `bmp.Dispose()` and `img.Dispose()` are not needed as you are in a `using` statement for them. `font`, `pic`, and `brush` should be in `using` statements, if a execption is thrown those three are not currently being cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion your code looks fine. Although I could imagine some a situation in which your code may cause an [OutOfMemoryException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

As you are using images, the *LargeObjectHeap* may come into play. Therefore **memory fragmentation** may be a problem which occurs when you run your code.
 (read [LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for further details)

So you may try using:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

I would like to hear if this solves your problem. In any case, if you could provide more details into this topic - this would be great!